# Replacing .* in vi

Tags: sed, regular-expression, vi

I need to replace all occurrences of "period asterisk" as it is shown here:

```
blah blah .*:.*:.* blah blah
```

with:

```
[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]
```

so that the end result looks like this:

```
blah blah [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] blah blah
```

I tried different variations of the following but it didn't work:

```
%s_ .*:.*:.* _ [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] _g
```

Answer (score 3):

You gave an example of a line with “period asterisk” repeated three times,
separated by colons. 
If your data will always look like that, you might as well stick
with [AlexP’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/394213/23408#394215). 
But your question *says*
that you need to replace all occurrences of “period asterisk”. 
If that *statement* of the problem is accurate, you should use

```
:%s/\.\*/[0-9][0-9]/g
```

which will find and replace “period asterisk”
even when it doesn’t appear in groups of three.

Comment: the `/cg` option at the end of the command (instead of just `/g` is useful as it allows one to "confirm" each replacement.

Answer (score 2):

For Vim: `:%s/\.\*:\.\*:\.\*/[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/g`

For `sed`: `sed -e 's/\.\*:\.\*:\.\*/[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/g'`.

- `%` means apply the substitution on all lines; is not needed in `sed` where by default the command is applied to all lines.
- `\.` is a period; a bare `.` means any character.
- `\*` is an asterisk; a bare `*` means 0 or more of the preceding atom.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `nomagic` modifier `\M` for the pattern in Vim:

```
:%s/\M.*/[0-9][0-9]/g
```

The `\M` will remove the specialness of both `.` and `*` in the pattern.

See [`:help magic`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27nomagic%27) in Vim.